# bool' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma?

Tags: python, python-3.x, arduino, arduino-uno, pyfirmata

I am trying to run this python code. Can anyone tell me how ho solve this issue?

```
from pyfirmata import Arduino 
from time import sleep

port = 'COM9'
board=Arduino(port)

pin = board.get_pin('a:0:i')
it = pyfirmata.util.iterator(board)
it.start()

while True():
    analog_value = pin.read()
    # voltage = float(analog_value*(5.0/1023.0))
    print(analog_value )
    # print(voltage)
    sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, where the code says `while True():`, what do you expect the `()` to mean, and why write them? (If you cannot find a problem like this yourself, then you should follow a tutorial to learn the fundamentals of the language, and also learn some [basic debugging skills](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), before trying to work on this sort of project. At the very least, you should know to read the error message, see where in the code it is pointing, and understand the problem it describes.)

Answer (score 1):

```
()
```

Is not needed when writing a `while True` statement.

Comment: Okay it worked, but why '()' is not needed?

Comment: () is not needed because with a while True you're not passing any parameters, and it's a statement, not a function.